# VSTS Missing azure web app location

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I have setup a project with VSTS and a build service. Currently working on setting up a release definition but for some reason when i choose my azure subscription it doese not show me the location where my app is currently set.I have connected with azure with a certificate.

[image]

In my case i have the Web app currently located in North Europe and according to the tooltip on the right it should be available.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, did you try clicking the "Refresh" button to refresh the location list?

Comment: Yeah, clicked refresh but its the same result. I also tried to remove the sub and re-add it but still not luck.

Comment: Does it work in build definition? And try cleaning the browser cache.

Comment: And before you get the dropdown list work, you can enter "North Europe" in it directly.

Comment: Not working in build definition either, and tested with multiple browser on multiple computers. Also tried to enter "North Europe" but thats not working either.

Comment: When you create a web app from Azure Portal, how many regions are available? And are you using the same account to get the publish settings file with certificate?

Comment: Coming up in App Service Plan with full list of available locations with the same account i used to get the certificate.